# Acumatica how to get notification for supplier detail change

Tags: acumatica

Is it possible in Acumatica to get a notification when certain fields or any field in supplier file changes? for example if someone changes supplier bank account details then a notification would fire up so accounts payable department can monitor such changes?
Thanks

Comment: It is not possible now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not possible in direct way. But I can propose you workaround. You can extend forms where your classes are changed and then send notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Please check [Notifications About Changes](https://docref.acumatica.com/wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=f8e59217-5c64-4805-b30f-e06735b4ad03) in Acumatica Help - hopefully this is enough for the accounts payable department to monitor changes.